# basic example with transfinite induction

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am trying to get my head around transfinite induction and recursion (class forms), and would like to check my understanding.  I begin with induction.

Proposition: Each $V_{\alpha}$ is $\in$-transitive -- i.e., if $y \in V_{\alpha}$ and $z \in y$, then $z \in V_{\alpha}$ as well.

Proof: Let $A$ be the class: $\{\gamma : V_{\gamma} \text{is} \, \in-\text{transitive}\}$.  We show that $A = V$.

(Base Case) $\emptyset$ is vacuously in $A$.

(Successor Case) Suppose that $\beta \in A$, and that $y \in V_{\beta+}$ and $z \in y$.  Then $y \subseteq V_{\beta}$, so $z \in V_{\beta}$.  Since $V_{\beta} \subseteq V_{\beta+}$, $z \in V_{\beta+}$.  So, $\beta+$ is in $A$ as well.

(Limit Case) Finally, let $\lambda$ be a limit ordinal, and suppose that $\beta \in A$ whenever $\beta < \lambda$.  Then $y \in V_{\lambda}$ means that $y \in V_{\beta}$ for some $\beta < \lambda$.  Since each $V_{\beta}$ is $\in$-transitive, so is $V_{\lambda}$.  Hence, $\lambda \in A$.

Is that correct?  Thanks, in advance.

Comment: Looks good to me

Comment: Thanks!  In that case, I will be back soon asking you to check more confusing (for me) examples!